# Confusion Matrix shows extra 0's

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to compute how well my model is at predicting if a bad loan were to happen. However, when I add margins to my confusion matrix, there is a top row of 0's. I can't figure out how to delete out just the top row of 0's for the computation to be accurate.

```
    threshold <- .5

    oversample_model <- glm(status ~., oversamp_training_data, family="binomial")

    predicted.oversample <- ifelse(predict(oversample_model, newdata = testing_data, type="response") > threshold, 1,0)

    actual.oversample <- testing_data$status
    conf_matrix_oversample <- table(actual.oversample,predicted.oversample)
    conf_matrix_oversample[apply(conf_matrix_oversample!=0, 1, all),]
    addmargins(conf_matrix_oversample)
p4 <- sum(diag(conf_matrix_oversample)) / sum(conf_matrix_oversample)
print(paste('Proportion correctly predicted = ', p4))
```

The output looks like this:

```
                     predicted.oversample
actual.oversample    0    1  Sum
                     0    0    0
             Bad   435  994 1429
             Good 3260 1806 5066
             Sum  3695 2800 6495
[1] "Proportion correctly predicted =  0.153040800615858"
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the 0's in the second row?

Comment: What does `levels(testing_data$status)` show? It looks like you might have a blank factor level in that column.

Comment: This is what it's showing: {""     "Bad"  "Good"}

Comment: Fixed it: testing_data$status <- factor(testing_data$status). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.